# Disable emojis from softkeyboard android xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I would like to disable or restrict the user from typing in emoji in EditText. I tried by adding an input filter with a regular expression but it didn't work. It repeats the same text again and again.

```
public class EmojiFilter : Java.Lang.Object, IInputFilter
{
    string regex = "^[0-9A-Za-z #$,\\-\\.]{0,255}$";

    public ICharSequence FilterFormatted(ICharSequence source, int start, int end, ISpanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(dest.ToString(), regex) || dest.ToString().Equals(""))
        {
            return new Java.Lang.String(source.ToString());
        }

        return new Java.Lang.String(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

I want to disable it throughout all the EditText's in my application. Any simpler way to achieve this?

**Edit**
It still doesn't work with @Ilya Lavrov code. I still takes few of the smileys.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `EmojiFilter` to your EditText. This is the implementation:

```
    public class EmojiFilter: Java.Lang.Object, IInputFilter
    {
        public ICharSequence FilterFormatted(ICharSequence source, int start, int end, ISpanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
        {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
            {
                int type = Character.GetType(source.CharAt(i));

                if (type == Character.Surrogate || type == Character.OtherSymbol)
                    return new Java.Lang.String(string.Empty);
                else
                    return source;
            }

            return source;
        }
    }
```

How to use:

```
YourCustomEditText.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new EmojiExcludeFilter() });
```

For disable it throughout all the EditText's in your application you need create your own control like that:

```
[Register("EmojiExcludedEditText")]
public class EmojiExcludedEditText: EditText
{
    ...
    public EmojiExcludedEditText(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new EmojiExcludeFilter() });
    }
    ...
}
```

Happy codding! :)

Comment: Doesn't work. It still takes some of the smileys. Please check the update.